# While I hide my password in react-native password freezes to the beginning

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, textinput

```
const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
const [passwordVisibility, setPasswordVisibility] = useState(false);
<View style={styles.inputContainer}>
          <TextInput
            name="password"
            style={styles.inputField}
            autoCapitalize='none'
            value={password}
            autoCorrect={false}
            textContentType="newPassword"
            onChangeText={onChangeText}
            placeholder="Password"
            enablesReturnKeyAutomatically
            secureTextEntry={passwordVisibility}
          />
          <Pressable onPress={()=>{setPasswordVisibility(!passwordVisibility) , console.log(password)}}>
          <Icon name={passwordVisibility == true ? 'eye' : 'eye-off' } size={23} color='purple' />
          </Pressable>
          
        </View>
```

Here is my code .While I hide my password in react-native password freezes to the beginning . How can  I fix this

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

`onChangeText={onChangeText}` to `onChangeText={value => setPassword(value)}`

and assign the `password` to the value prop on the `TextInput`

```
<TextInput

  // current props

  onChangeText={value => setPassword(value)}
  value={password}
/>
```

Comment: It did not work

Comment: Any errors or logs you could share?

Comment: No . I think its initial property of text input